# Pandas Merge issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge one column values from `df2` to `df1`. `df1.merge(df2, how='outer')` seems to be what I needed but result is not what I wanted because of duplicate. Using 'on' introduces `_x` and `_y` which I don't want either.

In below Example: `sub=site1` in both `df1` and `df2` is same, then `'fred'` from `df2` replaces `'own'` of `df1`.

```
# Pandas Merge test:

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sub': ['site1', 'site2', 'site3'], 'iss': ['enc1', 'enc2', 'enc3'], 'rem': [1, 3, 5], 'own': ['andy', 'brian', 'cody']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sub': ['data1', 'data2', 'site1'], 'rem': [2, 4, 6], 'own': ['david', 'edger', 'fred']})

>>> df1
     sub   iss  rem    own
0  site1  enc1    1   andy
1  site2  enc2    3  brian
2  site3  enc3    5   cody

>>> df2
     sub  rem    own
0  data1    2  david
1  data2    4  edger
2  site1    6   fred

>>> df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
     sub   iss  rem    own
0  site1  enc1    1   andy
1  site2  enc2    3  brian
2  site3  enc3    5   cody
3  data1   NaN    2  david
4  data2   NaN    4  edger
5  site1   NaN    6   fred

>>> df1.merge(df2, on='sub', how='outer')
     sub   iss  rem_x  own_x  rem_y  own_y
0  site1  enc1    1.0   andy    6.0   fred
1  site2  enc2    3.0  brian    NaN    NaN
2  site3  enc3    5.0   cody    NaN    NaN
3  data1   NaN    NaN    NaN    2.0  david
4  data2   NaN    NaN    NaN    4.0  edger
```

Expected Output:

```
     sub   iss  rem    own
0  site1  enc1    1   fred
1  site2  enc2    3  brian
2  site3  enc3    5   cody
3  data1   NaN    2  david
4  data2   NaN    4  edger
```

Comment: then what's your expected result?

Comment: edit your question and add expected result to your question

Comment: Sorry Sir my update is not coming in tabular form. But I have same EXPECTING output above in initial posts.

Comment: @eshirvana Yes Sir I did had it in question post.

Comment: so you wanna update `own` in df1 based on df2 for the same `sub` and if doean't exist add a new row ?

Comment: Yes Sir exactly. So 'data1' and 'data2' from df2 did not exists in df1 so 2 new rows with NaN for 'iss'. 'site1' exists in df1 and df2 so 'andy' in df1 is replaced with 'fred'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# update the df1.own with the values for it in the df2
# using map
df1['own'] = df1['sub'].map(df2.set_index('sub')['own']).fillna(df1['own'])


out=(pd.concat([df1, df2])            # concat the two DF
.drop_duplicates(subset=['sub'])      # drop duplicates
.reset_index()                        # reset index
.drop(columns='index'))               # remove the unwanted column

out
```

```
    sub     iss     rem     own
0   site1   enc1    1   fred
1   site2   enc2    3   brian
2   site3   enc3    5   cody
3   data1   NaN     2   david
4   data2   NaN     4   edger
```

**alternately**,

```
# merge the two DF, and drop the duplicates
out=(pd.concat([df1, df2])
.drop_duplicates(subset=['sub'])
.reset_index()
.drop(columns='index'))

# map the own in the resulting DF from concat
out['own'] = out['sub'].map(df2.set_index('sub')['own']).fillna(out['own'])
out
```

```
sub     iss     rem     own
0   site1   enc1    1   fred
1   site2   enc2    3   brian
2   site3   enc3    5   cody
3   data1   NaN     2   david
4   data2   NaN     4   edger
```

Comment: thank you this works. with 
`df['own'] = df1['sub'].map(df2.set_index('sub')['own']).fillna(df1['own'])`
`df3=(pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['sub']).reset_index().drop(columns='index')) `
 One question if I want to maintain df1 and df2 and only create 'out' new one, how can I do that. Thank you and appreciate it very much.

Comment: @alisyed, added the alternate solution, it keeps the df1 and df2 as is, and only updates the out, as you indicated. check it out

Answer (score 0):

A potential somewhat simple solution using `pd.concat` and `loc` to filter df1 to just contain records not present in df2 and then concat them together.

```
# used to make use loc on index as it is a bit simpler.
df1 = df1.set_index('sub')
df2 = df2.set_index('sub')
```

Then `pd.concat` them together.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)],df2])
```

Output:

```
print(df3)
        iss  rem    own
sub                    
site2  enc2    3  brian
site3  enc3    5   cody
data1   NaN    2  david
data2   NaN    4  edger
site1   NaN    6   fred
```

This does not change the value of `rem` and `iss` for site1 to equal the value of `df1` though.
If that is also needed you would you could just add an additional `loc` statement as a possible solution. Like this:

```
df3.loc[(df3.index.isin(df1.index.to_list())) & ~(df3['rem'].isin(df1['rem'].to_list())), ['iss','rem']] = df1[['iss','rem']]
```

#### Final Output

```
        iss  rem    own
sub                    
site2  enc2    3  brian
site3  enc3    5   cody
data1   NaN    2  david
data2   NaN    4  edger
site1  enc1    1   fred
```

Comment: This one-liner really works. 
`df3.loc[(df3.index.isin(df1.index.to_list())) & ~(df3['rem'].isin(df1['rem'].to_list())), ['iss','rem']] = df1[['iss','rem']]`. If I don't want to make 'sub' a index, please what changes to do in this one-liner. Thanks.

Comment: You can always just use `reset_index()` after to have `sub` not be part of the index. Otherwise the `loc` method is a bit messy as it assigns records values based on the index.

If you want to do it without altering the index **(I don't recommend this)** you could split the `loc` statement into two and assign the values for each column so that the index is not needed to correctly alter the records

Comment: Messy in the comments, sry!

This one alters the `iss` field:
`df3.loc[(df3['sub'].isin(df1['sub'].to_list())) & ~(df3['rem'].isin(df1['rem'].to_list())), ['iss']] = df1.loc[(df1['sub'].isin(df3['sub'].to_list())) & ~(df1['rem'].isin(df3['rem'].to_list())), 'iss'].item()`

Followed by altering the `rem` field: 
`df3.loc[(df3['sub'].isin(df1['sub'].to_list())) & ~(df3['rem'].isin(df1['rem'].to_list())), ['rem']] = df1.loc[(df1['sub'].isin(df3['sub'].to_list())) & ~(df1['rem'].isin(df3['rem'].to_list())), 'rem'].item()`

Comment: This is perfect.  **`reset_index(inplace=True)`** 
My final solution

`df1 = df1.set_index('sub')
df2 = df2.set_index('sub')
df3.loc[(df3.index.isin(df1.index.to_list())) & ~(df3['rem'].isin(df1['rem'].to_list())), ['iss','rem']] = df1[['iss','rem']]
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: changed to using update instead of fillna as per @bkeesey's comment

you need to merge on sub then update the new columns and drop the old ones

try

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sub': ['site1', 'site2', 'site3'], 'iss': ['enc1', 'enc2', 'enc3'], 'rem': [1, 3, 5], 'own': ['andy', 'brian', 'cody']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sub': ['data1', 'data2', 'site1'], 'rem': [2, 4, 6], 'own': ['david', 'edger', 'fred']})

dfm = df1.merge(df2, on='sub', how='outer', suffixes=["_x",""])

dfm.own.update(dfm.own_x)
dfm.rem.update(dfm.rem_x)

del dfm["own_x"]
del dfm["rem_x"]
```

result

```
     sub   iss  rem    own
0  site1  enc1  6.0   fred
1  site2  enc2  3.0  brian
2  site3  enc3  5.0   cody
3  data1   NaN  2.0  david
4  data2   NaN  4.0  edger
```

Comment: Great possible solution. I think using `dfm.rem.update(dfm.rem_x)` would be better to match the expected result.

Comment: thanks, that is much better, i updated my answer to use update

Comment: Really good solution and with my limited knowledge I can understand also. But this updates 'rem' also. `site1 enc1 6.0 fred` should be `site1 enc1 1 fred`.

Comment: change the suffixes around in the merge statement, i.e. ```suffixes=["","_x"]```

Comment: I tried but still get `0  site1  enc1  6.0   fred`. [https://codeshare.io/78j7RE]

Comment: I think this could be fixed by changing `dfm.own.update(dfm.own_x)` ->  the original `dfm.own.fillna(dfm.own_x, inplace=True)`